# How to book an early morning taxi to Rome Airport?

Tags: trains, public-transport, italy, taxis

We are planning a travel to Rome and then to Paris during the first week of June 2019. Our flight from Italy to Paris is around 6:15 am. We are staying near Vittorio Emanuele metro station. What are our possibilities to go to Leonardo da Vinci International Airport in Early morning? how reliable are cab companies if I book a cab before that night?

Comment: We ended up booking a taxi through our Airbnb host and it cost us EUR 55.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a ride hailing app- I have used Mytaxi successfully in Europe.

Entering in your parameters I get EUR 38-58 for a taxi from the monument to the airport you mention. Availability is 1 minute at the moment.

You usually just get ready then request a cab, but if you really want you can request at a specific time.

When you request the cab in real time the location is shown on the app as soon as it is dispatched so you can follow it as it approaches. Personally I would not book ahead but check the latency time after getting up and request it when ready. It will likely be just minutes.

There may be other apps, this one I have some experience with- it seemed a bit buggy at times, but it got the job done.